# How can I use the actual datetime for a field in Odoo 11

Tags: datetime, odoo-11

I want some like datetime.now() or similar in Odoo 11 to get the actual date and time.

I tried the code I saw in another answers in stawoverflow, but doesn´t works for me. Can someone put an example for how to do it?

Examples that doesn´t works:

```
exit = fields.Datetime('Date current action', required=False, readonly=False, select=True, default=lambda self: fields.datetime.now())

exit = fields.Datetime(string="Date current action", default=lambda *a: datetime.now())

exit= fields.Date.context_today(self, timestamp=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
default=fields.Datetime.now
```

You can find an example at [sale.py](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/addons/sale/models/sale.py#L128).

The following explanation is taken from [Odoo 11 ORM API](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/orm.html#fields)

> > class odoo.fields.Datetime(string=, **kwargs)
> >      ...
> >
> > For default values fields.datetime.now() should be used instead.

**Edit**
You can also use `time` module to set default values

[default=lambda *a: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/addons/account/wizard/account_report_aged_partner_balance.py#L18)

Comment: can i do this similarly with time only?

Comment: @JuanSebastianOcampoOspina Check my edit. Use `%H:%M:%S` to get current time.

Answer (score 3):

```
from datetime import datetime

    exit = fields.Date(string='Date Current Action',default=datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use lambda For example in Odoo 8 to Odoo 14 :

exit = fields.Datetime(string="Date",  default=lambda *a: datetime.now())